# What's the mechanism behind mineral oil loosening cyanoacrylate bonds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, bond, adhesion

Per industry literature I found that mineral oil is used to loosen out "super glue" and aid in removal from skin. I am exploring the chemistry of this loosening and I am intrigued. Please help me find which option applies here:

1. Does the mineral oil disturb the cohesive forces of the cured cyanoacrylate?
2. Does the mineral oil interact with the oil on the skin to loosen the cured adhesive and thus break the bond between skin and cyanoacrylate?
3. Does the mineral oil break the bond between the skin and cyanoacrylate by another mechanism?

Based on this answer, I am trying to find out if mineral oil will loosen the cured cyanoacrylate on a different substrate as well, namely PVC plastic. Please help!